# Java 2D array and Scanner

Tags: java, arrays

I'm trying to display "Number not found" when i input a number that is not in the list ...
I can't figure out what is wrong with the code.

my code:

```
import java.util.*;
public class Searchu {
static Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int  [][] x = new int [1][5];
        int k , z=0 , y , item , item1 ;



        System.out.println( "Enter 5 numbers: ");

        for ( y= 0 ; y < 5 ; y++) 
            for ( z =0 ; z < 1 ; z++) 
                x[z][y] = console.nextInt();



        System.out.println( "Search Number: ");
        k = console.nextInt();
        for ( item= 0 ; item < 5 ; item++) {
            for ( item1= 0 ; item1 < 1 ; item1++) {


                    if (x[item1][item] == k) {
                        System.out.println( " Position: "+  (item+1));

                        break;
                        }}}


        if (x[z][y] == 5)
            System.out.print("Number not found...");


}}
```

Comment: What is `if (x[z][y] == 5)` trying to check?

Comment: Why do you need a 2D array, it only complicates things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your error was the last checking. I added a flag about whether we found the number. I agree with the comments, you do not need to use 2D array.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[][] x = new int[1][5];
    int k, z = 0, y, item, item1;

    System.out.println("Enter 5 numbers: ");

    for (y = 0; y < 5; y++)
        for (z = 0; z < 1; z++)
            x[z][y] = console.nextInt();


    System.out.println("Search Number: ");
    k = console.nextInt();
    boolean isFound = false;
    for (item = 0; item < 5; item++) {
        for (item1 = 0; item1 < 1; item1++) {
            if (x[item1][item] == k) {
                System.out.println(" Position: " + (item + 1));
                isFound = true;
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    if (!isFound)
        System.out.print("Number not found...");
}
```

If you use a one-dimensional array, your code will look like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] array = new int[5];
    int target;

    System.out.println("Enter 5 numbers: ");

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        array[i] = console.nextInt();
    }

    System.out.println("Search Number: ");
    target = console.nextInt();
    boolean isFound = false;
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        if (array[i] == target) {
            System.out.println("Position: " + (i + 1));
            isFound = true;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (!isFound) {
        System.out.print("Number not found...");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply create an Arraylist and add all the elements in it. An ArrayList is less complicated and better for this particular case. Whenever you need to check any element present in the list or not, simply use the contains method.

```
import java.util.*;

public class Searchu {

    static Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ArrayList<Integer> x = new ArrayList<>();
        int k, z = 0, y, item, item1;

        System.out.println( "Enter 5 numbers: ");
        for ( y= 0 ; y < 5 ; y++) 
             x.add(console.nextInt());

        System.out.println( "Search Number: ");
        k = console.nextInt();

        if(x.contains(k)){
            System.out.println("found");
        } else {
            System.out.println("not found");
       }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

please verify when your itemindex is at limit(5) and tag the first 'for' in order to break all search iterations.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int[][] x = new int[1][5];
    int k, z = 0, y, item, item1;


    System.out.println("Enter 5 numbers: ");

    for (y = 0; y < 5; y++)
        for (z = 0; z < 1; z++)
            x[z][y] = console.nextInt();

    System.out.println("Search Number: ");
    k = console.nextInt();

    ext:
    for (item = 0; item < 5; item++) {
        for (item1 = 0; item1 < 1; item1++) {
            if (x[item1][item] == k) {
                System.out.println(" Position: " + (item + 1));
                break ext;
            }
        }
    }

    if (item == 5)
        System.out.print("Number not found...");

}
```

Answer (score 0):

With the "break" you are exiting only from the second for loop,please try the below code.

```
      import java.util.*;
      public class Searchu {
      static Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
      public static void main(String[] args) {

    int  [][] x = new int [1][5];
    int k , z=0 , y , item , item1,pos=0 ;
    boolean flag=false;
    System.out.println( "Enter 5 numbers: ");
    for ( y= 0 ; y < 5 ; y++) 
        for ( z =0 ; z < 1 ; z++)           
            x[z][y] = console.nextInt();
    System.out.println( "Search Number: ");
    k = console.nextInt();
    for ( item= 0 ; item < 5 ; item++) {
        for ( item1= 0 ; item1 < 1 ; item1++) {              
                if (x[item1][item] == k) {

                    flag=true;
                    pos=item+1;
                    }}}
       if(flag)
       {
        System.out.println( " Position: "+  (pos));
       }
        else
        {
        System.out.print("Number not found...");
        }
}}
```